# Trigger event.canvas.draw() with kivy button

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I'm trying to set up a matplotlib graph inside a kivy app that takes commands from kivy buttons, but am having difficulty triggering the event.canvas.draw() function to update the shown graph when a button triggers a method. Any ideas on how to get around this? Right now I have it set up to take a keypress to toggle the function, but I'd rather have 'button2' trigger the event.

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvas
import numpy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Builder(App):
    main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    top_layout = BoxLayout()
    bottom_layout = BoxLayout()
    main_layout.add_widget(top_layout)
    main_layout.add_widget(bottom_layout)

    def build(self):
        self.top_layout.add_widget(self.get_fc())
        self.bottom_layout.add_widget(Button(text='button1'))
        #self.bottom_layout.add_widget(Button(text='button2', on_press=self.pull_plots()))
        return self.main_layout

    def add_plot(self, event):

        if isinstance(event.ydata, (int, float, numpy.float64)) is False or isinstance(event.xdata, (int, float, numpy.float64)) is False or (event.ydata, event.xdata) != (
        event.ydata, event.xdata): return

        ax.plot(event.xdata, event.ydata, 'o', color='r')[0]
        event.canvas.draw()

    def pull_plots(self, event):
        try:
            del ax.lines[-1]
        except:
            pass
        event.canvas.draw()

    def get_fc(self):
        global fig1, ax
        fig1 = plt.figure()
        ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot([], [])
        wid = FigureCanvas(fig1)
        fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.add_plot)
        fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.pull_plots)

        return wid


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Builder().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

There are two methods for the solution. The first method is using `fig1` and the second method is using Kivy ObjectProperty.

### Method 1 - Using fig1

- Replace `event.canvas.draw()` with `fig1.canvas.draw()`
- Invoke `fig1.canvas.draw()` in the `try` block after `del ax.lines[-1]` i.e. redraw canvas if there is any changes.
- Uncomment `'button2'`
- Replace parameter, `event` with `instance` in method `pull_plots()`

#### Snippets

```
class Builder(App):
    ...

    def build(self):
        ...
        self.bottom_layout.add_widget(Button(text='button2', on_press=self.pull_plots))
        ...

    def pull_plots(self, instance):
        try:
            del ax.lines[-1]
            fig1.canvas.draw()    # re-draw canvas
        except:
            pass
```

### Method 2 - Using Kivy ObjectProperty

- Save the matplotlib mouse event to a Kivy [ObjectProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty), `mpl_mouse_event` when method
  `add_plot()` is invoked
- Replace `event.canvas.draw()` with `self.mpl_mouse_event.canvas.draw()`
- Invoke `fig1.canvas.draw()` in the `try` block after `del ax.lines[-1]` i.e. redraw canvas if there is any changes.
- Uncomment `'button2'`
- Replace parameter, `event` with `instance` in method `pull_plots()`

#### Snippets

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Builder(App):
    mpl_mouse_event = ObjectProperty(None)
    ...

    def build(self):
        ...
        self.bottom_layout.add_widget(Button(text='button2', on_press=self.pull_plots))
        ...

    def add_plot(self, event):
        self.mpl_mouse_event = event
        ...

    def pull_plots(self, instance):
        try:
            del ax.lines[-1]

            if self.mpl_mouse_event is not None:   
                self.mpl_mouse_event.canvas.draw()    # re-draw canvas
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Actually I do have a followup regarding this. The implementation provided herein assumes that add_plot (using a mpl_connect toggle in the graph) is called before pull_plots(). If I wanted to structure it so that we can call a button toggle as the first toggle, how might we do that?

Comment: Use `fig1` in replacement of `self.mpl_mouse_event`

Comment: When the answer is stupidly easy... 
So what's the reason for ever using event.canvas.draw() or self.mpl_mouse_event.canvas.draw()? Is this a convention or pythonic thing or is there a backend utility? IDK just seems convoluting to this noob here haha